# ¿Porqué la ventana modal queda detrás de un footer?

Tags: html, bootstrap, jquery-ui

Quiero adaptar mi proyecto usando ventanas modales, pero al momento de abrir la modal, esta queda oscura y el footer queda adelante por asi decir, ¿que puede ser?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Quedan debajo porque la propiedad del z-index de la capa oscura es mayor a la del modal, y la del footer es mayor a la de todos. Solución rápida, dale un z-index exagerado al modal.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style"z-index: 100000">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> La propiedad de z-index especifica el ordenamiento de apilado de los elementos. Mientas mayor sea el z-index del elemento, lo más probable que este se mantenga en pantalla.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que te faltan dos `divs` que van a fuera del div de `modal-content`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" >
            <div class="model-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="model-body">
                <p>...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```